# Are parameterless constructors considered a best pratice in OOP

Tags: java, oop

When designing a class should I strive to make the constructor parameterless?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. You can have as many constructors as you want and you don't necessarily need the default constructor. **Your constructors should make sense for the purpose of the class**, that is the only best practice.

Comment: So the answer is 'It's not a best practice', but dependency injection does require parameterless constructors

Comment: Dependency injection does not require parameterless constructors, read up on "Constructor-Injection"

Comment: Sometimes (e.g. Hibernate mapping) you are **required** to have at least a (non-necessarily-public) parameterless constructor

Answer (score 3):

There are different thoughts on this. The JavaBeans pattern expects a default constructor and getters and setters to finalize an object. This, however, results in instances that can be in a state of limbo (refer to Effective Java by Josh Bloch for more on this).

Constructor parameters prevent any form of "magic" as you are required to provide the needed instances to create an instance of a class (aka dependency injection).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is neither yes or no: it depends.

Often, parameterized constructors are used to initialize an object with immutable (`final`) values. The first thing that comes into my mind is the following example.

```
public class Car {
     public Car(String chassisCode) {...}

     public String getChassisCode();

     public String getLicenseNumber() {...}
     public void setLicenseNumber(String value) {...}
}
```

Since the license plate registration number can change during the car's lifecycle, it can be implemented as a get/set property. The chassis registration code, instead, is unique for each car and **immutable**. A car can be changed its license plate any time, but the chassis number is immutable and registered with the documentation any time license plate or owner changes.

In other cases, you may want a "default" parameterless constructor to obtain a "default" behaviour of your class. An example

```
public class LightSwitch {
    private boolean state = false; //off

    public LightSwitch() {}

    public boolean getState();
    public void setState(boolean value);
}
```

In this case a light switch is considered to be off unless explicitly switched on.

Comment: Google suggests me to say "frame number" instead of "chassis number" :D

Comment: You've given the best explanation, but the answer to the question is 'No it's not a best practice'

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Default or "no-arg" constructors are often a useful feature for a class to have, but only as one of the available constructors, not as the *only* constructor. Establishing the important invariants of an object during construction is a *good* thing, and constructors with arguments are often a necessary part of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.  When using decoupling mechanisms, such as Dependency Injection, the parameters of a constructor are the perfect place to define immutable dependencies.  As well, any other immutable parameters for an object should go in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a case of a misunderstanding when hearing something out of context, incompletely hearing the advice or hearing it in a foreign language.
I suspect that you heard someone experienced say (perhaps over-emphatically) something like:

1) "You should always try to have a parameterless constructor."

Then you misunderstood this to mean:

2) "You should always try to have ONLY a parameterless constructor."

Statement (1) is true because if a parameterless constructor is called on the class concerned - or by a sub-class - and if none exists, then the compiler will create its own and the code's behaviour will be hard to predict.

Statement (2) is generally NOT true.